# Illegal instruction core dumped error after INSERT statement

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I am just developing simple logic to parse an `;` separated file as below, and insert its contents in a DB.
It's working fine, but at the last iteration of the `INSERT` statement, I get this error:

> selfdiag4.0.1 (157): undefined instruction: pc=020000fa Illegal instruction (core dumped).

My code is as follows:

```
int fileread() {
    char str1[1024];
    unsigned char catId[25]="",catName[50]="",prefix[25]="",status[10]="";
    char *ptr;
    char temp[1024];
    int i=1,t,rc=0;
    char delims[]=";";
    char filename[100] ="/mnt/jffs2/category.txt";
    FILE *fp;
    rc=0;
    fp= fopen("/mnt/jffs2/category.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("No such file");
        return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(str1,sizeof(str1),fp) !=NULL) {
        ptr=strtok(str1,delims);
        while(ptr != NULL) {
            i=1;
            memset(catId,0,sizeof(catId));
            memset(catName,0,sizeof(catName));
            memset(prefix,0,sizeof(prefix));
            memset(status,0,sizeof(status));
            while(ptr!=NULL && i<=8) {
                strcpy(temp, ptr);
                ptr = strtok(NULL,delims);
                switch(i) {
                    case 2: strcpy(catId,temp);
                        break; //insert into categoryId
                    case 4: Strcpy(catName,temp);
                        break;
                    case 6: Strcpy(prefix,temp);
                        break;
                    case 8: strcpy(status,temp);
                        break;
                    default:break;
                } //end switch
                i++;
            } //end while
            rc=execute("INSERT INTO category(category_id,category_name,prefix,status) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s');",catId,catName,prefix,status);
            printf("\nIn While Loop\n");
            if (rc == 0) return error_handler(rc);
        } // end while
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are your indexes in the switch statement 1-based or or 0-based? It looks like you pull out two tokens in the first iteration through this code with two calls to strtok() but assign the second token index 1. Is that intended?

Comment: @Kut S yup that was intendedly written to parse this file CatId;1;CatName;CLOTHS;Prefix;CH;ActiveStatus;Y;

Comment: How many items do you expect per line of input? If there are only 4 (+4 skipped) you can omit the outer loop.

Comment: What does `Strcpy` do? Also `execute` is missing :/ I would say, that the problem lies within the `execute` statement or with the way you use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* these are for testing */
#define execute printf
#define error_handler(i) fprintf(stderr, "Error(%d)\n", i )

int fileread(char *filename )
{
        char buff[1024];
        size_t off,len, cnt;
        char *ptrs[10];
        int rc=0;
        char delims[]=";\n\r";
        FILE *fp;

        fp= fopen(filename, "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "No such file: %s\n", filename);
            return 1;
            }
        while(fgets(buff,sizeof buff,fp) ) {
            for(cnt=off = 0; buff[off] ; off+= len ) {
                ptrs[cnt++] = buff + off;
                len = strcspn(buff+off, delims );
                if (!len) break;
                buff[len+off] = '\0';
                len += 1;
                if (cnt >= 10) { fprintf(stderr, "Too many items\n" ); break; }
                }
            if (cnt < 8) continue;
            /* if you expect repeating groups, 
            ** you should iterate here. And resize ptrs[] */
            rc=execute(
                "INSERT INTO category(category_id,category_name,prefix,status)"
                " VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s');\n"
                ,ptrs[1],ptrs[3],ptrs[5],ptrs[7]);
                if(rc == 0)return error_handler(rc);
            }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
char *filename ="/mnt/jffs2/category.txt";
int rc;

rc = fileread (filename);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used this approach because is suspect your SIGSEGV/SIGILL  is caused by a buffer overflow in one of the string copying operations in the original program. My version keeps all the data in the input buffer, and just puts a few '\0' characters at strategic places in that same buffer.